# all db records get updated instead of only 1 CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am working on a school project.

I have a validateUser function in my Users.php controller:

```
public function validateUser()
{
    $data = [];

    UserModel::validateUser($this->request->getPost('id_user')); // validate the user

    if (session()->get('success')) 
    {
        return redirect()->to('admin_panel');
    } 
    else 
    {
        
        echo view('templates/header', $data);
        echo view('admin_panel2',$data);
        echo view('templates/footer');
    }
}}
```

This is my validateUser function in my UserModel.php

```
public static function validateUser($id_user)
{
    
    $model = new UserModel();

    $data =  ['id_role' => '2'];

    $model->update($id_user,$data);

    session()->setFlashdata('success', 'Successfuly Validated');
}
```

My view

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="container">
            <p></p>
            <div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h6 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
                                <?php
                                echo "<h3>Users To Validate</h3>";
                                ?>
                            </a>
                            <?php

                            ?>
                        </h6>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h4></h4>
                            <ol>
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-sm8- offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 mt-5 pt-3 pb-3 bg-white form-wrapper">
                                            <div class="container">
                                                <?php if (session()->get('success')) : ?>
                                                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                                        <?= session()->get('success') ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php foreach ($usersToValidate as $row)
                                                    echo '<li class="nav-item">' . $row->firstname . '  ' . $row->lastname . '<a class="nav-link active" href="validate_user?id_user='.$row->id_user.'">Validate</a></li>';



                                                ?>
                                                <ul class="nav">

                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <hr>
            <?php if (isset($permissions)) : ?>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">

                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php else :   ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (isset($validation)) : ?>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        <?= $validation->listErrors() ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php else :   ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that in my 'users' table all 'id_role' records get changed to '2'. I only wish to update a single record in the db.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Take a look at what the UserModels `update()` method does

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update#update: 1st the data array, then the where string

Comment: @Vickel thanks mate, I did do that before asking questions here and I don't get any errors but nothing gets updated in the db either...

This is what I did

$model = new UserModel();
        $model  ->set($data);
        $model  ->where('id_user',$id_user);

        $model  ->update($data);

Comment: @AlexAnghel That is the CI 3.0 method

Comment: I found the issue. I replaced $this->request->getPost('id_user') with getGet('id_user') in my controller function

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I replaced $this->request->getPost('id_user') with getGet('id_user') in my controller function

```
    public function validateUser()
{
    $data = [];

    UserModel::validateUser($this->request->getGet('id_user')); // validate the user

    if (session()->get('success')) 
    {
        return redirect()->to('admin_panel');
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo view('templates/header', $data);
        echo view('admin_panel2',$data);
        echo view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```